# Cannot recognise i2c device

Tags: i2c, pi-zero-w, raspberry-pi-os-buster

I appreciate this may be a duplicate question, but I have spent days working through answers to other questions and none work for me.  Most similar questions predate the debian buster release, which I know changed slightly how I2C is enabled, so I wonder if all are still relevant.

I am trying and failing to get my Raspberry Pi Zero W to recognise any I2C devices.  I've tried across multiple devices and multiple Pi Zero W's, and get the same (lack of) results on each.

What I did:

- I followed [this tutorial](https://www.abelectronics.co.uk/kb/article/1/i2c--smbus-and-raspbian-linux) (and many others).  EDIT Actual instructions typed:

```
sudo reboot
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-smbus python3-smbus python-dev python3-dev i2c-tools
sudo i2cdetect -y 1
```

- I connected a [BlinkM ThingM](https://thingm.com/products/blinkm) as follows:

  1. BlinkM:d -> RPi GPIO2/SDA1 I2C
  2. BlinkM:c -> RPi GPIO3/SCL1 I2C
  3. BlinkM:+/- to a separate 5V power source

[image]

(I also tried a [LuMini ring](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/14967) and a [Lumenati Stick](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/14359), and tried two other RPi Zeros with identical results in case it was a hardware problem)

The results I get:

```
pi@HA-RPZW-0001:~ $ sudo i2cdetect -y 1
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
pi@HA-RPZW-0001:~ $ sudo i2cdetect -y 0
Error: Could not open file `/dev/i2c-0' or `/dev/i2c/0': No such file or directory
```

I have tried:

Ensuring I2C (and SPI) are enabled in raspi-config

Verifying parameters are set correctly in config.txt:

```
pi@HA-RPZW-0001:~ $ cat /boot/config.txt | grep dtparam
dtparam=i2c_arm=on
#dtparam=i2s=on
dtparam=spi=on
dtparam=audio=on
```

Verifying there is a device in /dev:

```
pi@HA-RPZW-0001:~ $ ls /dev/ | grep i2c
i2c-1
```

Checking the modules are loaded:

```
pi@HA-RPZW-0001:~ $ lsmod | grep i2c
i2c_bcm2835            16384  0
i2c_dev                16384  0
```

Ensuring all python modules are loaded:

```
pi@HA-RPZW-0001:~ $ sudo apt-get install python-smbus python3-smbus python-dev python3-dev i2c-tools
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
i2c-tools is already the newest version (4.1-1).
python-dev is already the newest version (2.7.16-1).
python-smbus is already the newest version (4.1-1).
python3-dev is already the newest version (3.7.3-1).
python3-smbus is already the newest version (4.1-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I am running:

```
pi@HA-RPZW-0001:~ $ cat /etc/os-release | grep "PRETTY"
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
```

Can anyone help?

SOLUTION:

Connect ground on power supply to ground on RPi.  Never realised that was a thing, but i2c device now detected, thank you all!

Comment: Did you connect the pi's ground and the ground from the 5v supply together?

Comment: I skimmed the AB Electronics UK tutorial, though published 2015 but updated 2020 and found it as usual good.  My bad experience with RpiZ/W is that even new buster drivers working happily with Rpi3B+ might not work with RpiZ/W because the hardware the driver drives is different between Rpi3B+ and RpiZW. It is like old PC/Win7 PnP auto detect drivers won't work with new PC/Win10, because of hardware/software incompatibility problems. Often it is the hardware, eg USB to TTL adapter must must change. But old hardware built in RpiZ/W can not change. / to continue, ...

Comment: Only hope is to wait for new hardware version of RpiZ/W, which of course might never come. Now ***My troubleshooting suggestions***: (1)  Swap with Rpi3B+/Rpi4B buster and test again. (2) This config line might cause trouble: ***core_freq=250***. I have been setting up I2C, using CLI and GUI  Rpi config tools, perhaps 100+ times, since Rpi1 days, I never set up core frequency, because I never saw this config line.  I did not skim the tutorial complete, because tutorial published two or three years ago often have conflict setup, eg old settup uses cmdline.txt. / to continue, ...

Comment: In short, I ***never use cmdline.txt*** perhaps after whizzy or jessie, and ***never set core frequency***. Of course there might be other possible causes of trouble, eg, those ***mysterious device tree drivers*** . Good luck and cheers.

Comment: "I followed this tutorial" and it doesn't work means either the tutorial is wrong OR you didn't follow it. If you want help **tell us what YOU did**. Did you ensure that the modules you used **DID NOT have pullup to 5V** - most modules designed for 5v operation on Arduino DO! If so you may have damaged the Pi and you should test the GPIO pins.

Comment: Please edit your question and include a clear photo or photos showing the connections between the Pi and the device.  We need to be able to see which Pi pin is connected to which device pin in sufficient detail to identify each pin.

Comment: @SteveRobillard no I didn't.  Are you suggesting that's something I should do, or checking to make sure I didn't do it?

Comment: @tlfong01 hardware incompatibility might make sense given what I've seen so far.  I don't have any RPi3+'s around, but I could try something similar by checking whether any known good I2C devices work with the Zero.  Does anyone maintain a list of I2C devices known to work with the Zero's?   Re the core_freq line, I hadn't set that yet as results had already diverged from expected before tthat step

Comment: @joan photo added.  Sorry, thought the pin connection list was easier to read.

Comment: @Milliways actual commands added, not sure if that will help significantly in this case though, they were relatively simple.  No, I did not ensure modules don't have pullup to 5V and would not know how to do that, could you possibly explain?

Comment: I can not see a ground connection between pi and breadboard.

Comment: @joan that's because there isn't one.  Should there be?

Comment: @joan bless you, yes there should.

Comment: Yes, without a ground the breadboard side has no idea if the pi GPIO are high or low.

Comment: Bless Steve, it was the first comment.

Comment: @weegolo, Yes, I agree if you don't have any Rpi3 lying around, trying another I2C device is the second best option. Good luck and cheers..

Answer (score 1):

As Steve has mentioned your fundamental problem is lack of a ground connection.
**ANY electrical circuit NEEDS to be complete.** That means that you need a loop for current to flow.
This is most commonly provided by a connection between the ground of the circuits.

The (not very good) tutorial you linked fails to mention this because it is "obvious". Indeed it fails to mention any of the other electrical issues of concern using I²C.

I²C requires pullup to work. All Pi models have on-board 1.8kΩ pullups on I²C pins 3,5.

Many modules designed for 5v operation on Arduino have pullup to 5V which would have to be removed or you would need a level converter to safely interface to the 3.3V circuitry on the Pi. The link to BlinkM ThingM  does not mention these, although it mentions "5-volt standard TTL inputs".

There are very many posts on this site discussing the issues with interfacing the Pi using I²C e.g. https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/108856/8697

NOTE Your photo shows a 9V battery, which would not last very long. It is also unnecessary. The Pi 5V pins will easily provide sufficient current for the device.